# How to extract month from a Date variable?

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
 dtNextVisit=cal.getTime();
 out.println(dtNextVisit);
```

I am not including all code here. This displays `"Sun Jan 17 02:53:40 PST 2016"` in result because month is January.
Now I want to extract and store the month to another variable suppose:

```
int month=0;
```

it should display `1`.

Comment: Use [Calendar.get(int field)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-), like `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)`.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has already been covered many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

month will have 1

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
import java.time.*;
class ABC{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().getMonthValue());
    }
}
```

Edit: I missed up value..

Comment: i know all this .. give me some specific code.. to display the month value.

Comment: doesn't making any sense,, ok... suppose a timestamp ( Sun Jan 17 03:15:05 PST 2016  ) is stored in a variable X. now how extract & display the month value from that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for string to date king of conversion, Then java.text.SimpleDateFormat is the one you need to be used. using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html this link you solve anything. Mark it as answer if correct.

```
public class Test {    
public int getMonth(String dateText) throws ParseException {

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
   Date myday = sdf.parse(dateText);
   System.out.println(myday.getMonth()+1);
   return myday.getMonth() + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {  
  String date = "Sun Jan 17 02:53:40 PST 2016";
  new Test().getMonth(date);
}
}
```

Comment: Also title should be modified as [How to extract month from a Date text?]